# Grails 2.0 dependency resolution with HtmlUnit and Release plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, dependencies, grails-plugin

I'm writing a plugin that uses HtmlUnit and I ran into a dependency issue this morning.  By default when you create a plugin the tomcat and release plugins are added.  I added a dependency for HtmlUnit and started recieving errors when instantiating an instance of HtmlUnitDriver.

My BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
    test("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:$seleniumVersion") {
        exclude "xml-apis"
    }
}

plugins {
    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    //build ":release:1.0.0"
}
```

Simple Test Case:

```
@Test
void stuff() {
    def driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true)
}
```

When the release plugin is not included the test passes.  When the release plugin is included the test fails with: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.` I googled around for that error and came across this:

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GEB-0-6-0-throwing-grails-geb-java-lang-NoSuchMethodError-org-apache-http-conn-scheme-Scheme-lt-init-td3766109.html

How can I use the release plugin (I'm assuming I'll need it eventually to release the plugin) and not have it screw with my version of HtmlUnit?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you uninstall the release plugin and only install it when you actually need to release the plugin?

Alternatively, can you upgrade HtmlUnit so it has dependencies that are new enough to not conflict with the release plugin? I looks like the latest version of HtmlUnit uses a recent httpclient.

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/dependencies.html